# How do I load a specific git commit?

Tags: git

I cloned a repository and want to switch to a commit to test my plugin against the core.

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Instead of passing the name of a branch, you can pass any commit ID to `checkout`:

```
git checkout <commit-id>
```

[See the `man` page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout).

Comment: Ah did it :) I thought that checkout only allows branch names.

Comment: When you check out a non-branch object (a commit by its ID or a tag), you get a detached head. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965676

Comment: When you want to go back to the latest commit just use "git checkout nameOfYourBranch"

Comment: Does commit ID means commit Hash here?

Comment: @Mario: Yes. The man page changed in the meantime and just mentions "commit" now.

Answer (score 20):

**Step 1:** fetch list of commits:

```
git log
```

You'll get list like in this example:

```
[Comp:Folder User$ git log
commit 54b11d42e12dc6e9f070a8b5095a4492216d5320
Author: author <author@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Jul 8 23:42:22 2016 +0300

This is last commit message

commit fd6cb176297acca4dbc69d15d6b7f78a2463482f
Author: author <author@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Jun 24 20:20:24 2016 +0300

This is previous commit message

commit ab0de062136da650ffc27cfb57febac8efb84b8d
Author: author <author@gmail.com>
Date:   Thu Jun 23 00:41:55 2016 +0300

This is previous previous commit message
...
```

**Step 2:** copy needed commit hash and paste it for checkout:

```
git checkout fd6cb176297acca4dbc69d15d6b7f78a2463482f
```

**Thats all.**

Comment: With git log --pretty="%h - %s" the user can get a shortened hash (and the commit message) that also works on git checkout.

Comment: Doesn't work, result:  fatal: your current branch 'master' does not have any commits yet

Comment: You should add some commits to master at first.

Comment: If it doesn't works, check the name of the commit again because VS code randomly edits what I paste with CTRL+V.

The text I copied: e7a7f97076ca40ec9fe43f04eed79d824aea2665
The text I pasted: e7a7f97076ca40ec9fe43f04eed79d824aea26651~